# Polarion description field broken on some work item type

Tags: polarion

For some reason, one of the work item type has a broken description field. When creating a new work item  'Requirement' in a document, opening the item, then clicking edit, the description box seems to drop down a bit but the rich text options etc are not shown and we can't change the text either.

[image]

Creating other work items doesn't cause this behaviour. Also tried in various browser just in case and various users. I've checked the Form Layouts but can't see what's wrong with this one.

Anyone having any suggestions?

Comment: It may be necessary to add more information about the version you are using and read-only-fields and form-layout.xml. For me it looks like the field is write protected.

Comment: Good point, current Polarion version is Build: 3.19.2.20190918-1514-e1943f37. Had a chat with a guy from onePLM earlier about this and his conclusion was this being a bug. We've created a brand new project, using the 'empty' template, and could reproduce the same behaviour.

Comment: Never mind, your comment John regarding the 'read only field' was correct. For some reason the global settings had read only field setup for 'title and description' for the '_default' status... Removing those cured the 'problem'. Thanks

Comment: That is a strange default config indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polarion hast a configuration for read-only-fields.
Check if this file contains configuration to protect these fields.